# Problems using wxWidgets (wxMSW) within multiple DLL instances

Tags: user-interface, dll, plugins, wxwidgets, vst

**Preface**

I'm developing VST-plugins which are DLL-based software modules and loaded by VST-supporting host applications. To open a VST-plugin the host applications loads the VST-DLL and calls an appropriate function of the plugin while providing a native window handle, which the plugin can use to draw it's GUI. I managed to port my original VSTGUI
code to the wxWidgets-Framework and now all my plugins run under wxMSW and wxMac but I still have problems under wxMSW to find a correct way to open and close the plugins and I am not sure if this is a wxMSW-only issue.

**Problem**

If I use any VST-host application I can open and close multiple instances of one of my VST-plugins without any problems. As soon as I open another of my VST-plugins besides my first VST-plugin and then close all instances of my first VST-plugin the application crashes after a short amount of time within the wxEventHandlerr::ProcessEvent function telling me that the wxTheApp object isn't valid any longer during execution of wxTheApp->FilterEvent (see below). So it seems to be that the wxTheApp objects was deleted after closing all instances of the first plugin and is no longer available for the second plugin.

```
bool wxEvtHandler::ProcessEvent(wxEvent& event)
{
    // allow the application to hook into event processing
    if ( wxTheApp )
    {
        int rc = wxTheApp->FilterEvent(event);
        if ( rc != -1 )
        {
            wxASSERT_MSG( rc == 1 || rc == 0,
                          _T("unexpected wxApp::FilterEvent return value") );

            return rc != 0;
        }
        //else: proceed normally
    }

    ....
}
```

**Preconditions**

1.) All my VST-plugins a dynamically linked against the C-Runtime and wxWidgets libraries. With regard to the wxWidgets
forum this seemed to be the best way to run multiple instances of the software side by side.

2.) The DllMain of each VST-Plugin is defined as follows:

```
// WXW
#include "wx/app.h"
#include "wx/defs.h"
#include "wx/gdicmn.h"
#include "wx/image.h"

#ifdef __WXMSW__
#include <windows.h>
#include "wx/msw/winundef.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain
( HANDLE hModule,
  DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
  LPVOID lpReserved )
{
        switch (ul_reason_for_call)
        {
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
                  wxInitialize();
                ::wxInitAllImageHandlers();
            break;
        }
            case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
                       break;
            case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
                       break;
            case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
                       wxUninitialize();
                           break;
        }

    return TRUE; 
}

#endif // __WXMSW__

class Application : public wxApp {};
IMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(Application)
```

**Question**

How can I prevent this behavior respectively how can I properly handle the wxTheApp object if I have multiple instances
of different VST-plugins (DLL-modules), which are dynamically linked against the C-Runtime and wxWidgets libraries?

Best reagards, Steffen

Comment: Since you don't have an answer yet, I suggest you ask over at kvraudio, where there are a lot of VST programmers. http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues using a LSP created with wxWidgets when an wxWidgets application loaded our DLL. Check for NULL == wxTheApp before calling ::wxInitialize().

Pseudo code:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch(dwReason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH :
            if(NULL == wxTheApp) {
                ::wxInitialize();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, I suggest doing as little possible in your DllMain() as possible, e.g. move wxInitAllImageHandlers() elsewhere if possible. Additionally, you may wish to track if you called ::wxInitialize() to pair up with ::wxUninitialize()

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue but with Acrobat plugins.
While adjusting our Acrobat plugins to Acrobat X (10) we had to remove code related to ADM (Acrobat Dialog Manager - Used to be a cross-platform GUI framework on Acrobat 7, 8 & 9. Removed with Acrobat X) and use a different GUI framework.

Acrobat SDK comes with samples of using wxWidgets as a cross-platform framework so we headed that way (we support MAC & Windows).
The plugin architecture of Acrobat is very similar to the one you described above: dlls (for Acrobat plugins the binary file extension is *.api) which are dynamically loaded by a main process (exe) and their functions are being called in a documented, pre-defined order.

Because the Acrobat wxWidgets example was written with 2.8.12 and due to the fact that this is the stable version we decided to NOT use the 2.9.x ongoing version.

So we statically linked our plugins (total of 3 different plugins) to the wx2.8.12 libs and found out that if 3 of them are installed, the two that were loaded last were not functioning. By that I mean - Our custom wxFrames, wxWindows & wxDialogs belonging to these two plugins were all messed up (like someone tried to erase them, with rubber :-)).

Digging deeply we narrowed it down to the fact that the first plugin being loaded, initializes wxWidgets and the latter do not, even though the explicit call to wxInitialize(). Something there went wrong....

Here I forgot to mention - In an Acrobat plugin you cannot change the DllMain() function, so the initialization of wx is done in a "Plugin Init() function".

Just to be clear - The wx libs are statically linked to the *.api files, so each should have a "copy" of its own and not influence on each other.

Using Google for 2-3 FULL days I managed to find [this](http://old.nabble.com/Adobe-Plugin-having-problems-with-wxPanel%27s-children-td22702458.html) post
,which suggested to apply [this](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/10562) patch (for 2.8x ONLY!!!). I believe (or hope) that the 2.9.x version does not suffer from this issue (didn't have the chance to check it).

BTW - The patch is only one file which is very clear, so reading the code to understand it and to be calm that it does no harm is pretty easy.

I hope others using wx 2.8.x and suffering from the same issue will find this.

Omri